# Two-digit RegEx Patterm Match in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, special-characters

The following expression:

```
targetString = targetString.replace(parenthesizedRegEx, "$3$1$11");
```

where parenthesizedRegEx is a valid parenthesized regular expression, replaces the matched text with a string that is the concatenation of the third item, the first item, the first item again, and the literal "1".  It is as if it is ignoring the "two-digit" parentheses-item index "$11" and treating it as "$1" and the literal "1".

Is there some escaping or other separating that should be used?

This result occurs in FF and IE9.

Thanks for your help.  I hope the answer is embarrassingly simple!!

**Edit Update:**

I did a jfiddle to demonstrate the issue comprehensively.  The regexp I am using includes a negative lookahead assertion.  It seems that when I include all the open parens for the assertion, it fails.  If I include none of the insertion's open parens, it also fails.  But if I include all but the assertion's initial opening paren, it works.  I know that groups formed with (?:...) are not numbered.  But is seems that one has to include all the other open parens within the assertion to get the count right.  So you will see in the jfiddle that $11 does not work but that $10 does.

http://jsfiddle.net/pxMFx/1/

Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Using `$11` in a replacement string works for me *when there are at least 11 groups in the regex*.  You should post the regular expression itself.

Comment: I guess you don't have the match `$11`. You can play with: `"1234567890".replace(/^(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)/, "$10")`. In my case it works perfectly in all browsers.

Comment: Please see the edit update.  There are indeed 11 groups in the regex, but one of them initiates a negative lookahead assertion.  The opening paren of that assertion apparently should not be counted but all the other parens in the assertion should be.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
var regex = /^(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w).*$/i;

alert("abcdefghijklmno".replace(regex,"$3$1$11"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J3RAa/

The key is that you need to match the whole string with your regular expression if you are targeting a specific location in it. Try taking the `.*` out of the above regex and you will see that it breaks the replacement.

Comment: Please see the edit update and comments to previous answer.  Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: If I take out the .* and the $, I get "caklmno", which is what I want, as I only want to replace the substring matched within the greater string.  I think you needed the .* because you were searching the beginning and ending of the string simultaneously.